# Override default foreground color for Flamingo's JCommandButton

Tags: java, swing, substance

I'm using Flamingo/Substance in a Swing application and can't figure out a simple way to affect the text color for a `JCommandButton`. Explicitly setting the foreground color seems to have no effect:

```
JCommandButton button = new JCommandButton("Button");
button.setForeground(Color.red);
```

Do I have to extend `JCommandButton` to do this? If so, how do I override this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the preferred way of doing it, but I ended up extending the delegate to get the result I wanted:

```
class CustomCommandButtonUI extends BasicCommandButtonUI {
  @Override
  protected Color getForegroundColor(boolean isTextPaintedEnabled) {
    return Color.red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, been on vacation and work deadlines and such.  Yes, this is currently how you must override the text color of a command button.  This sounds like an excellent RFE: https://github.com/insubstantial/insubstantial/issues